# Overlay multi-panel plot on single plot

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to overlay a multi-panel plot (using base graphics in R) over a single panel plot of a map. The multi-panel plot looks like this:

[image: multi-panel plot]

...and I wish to overlay this on a map (plotted using the maps package).

My code looks like this:

```
# Blank plot for map
plot(1, 1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", axes=F,
     xlim=c(-39,-35.5),ylim=c(-55,-54))
# Plot map
map("worldHires", regions="Falkland Islands:South Georgia",col="#BFBFBF",
  fill=F, add=T, bg="#7F7F7F", lwd=0.05) 
# Start overplotting
par(new=T)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(5,7,1,0))
hist(~yy$l.class[yy$strat=="SR"], breaks=classes, main="",xlab="",ylab="",
  col=cols[1], border=cols[1], probability=T, ylim=c(0,0.18),
  bg=rgb(1,1,1,0))
```

However, once I plot this first histogram, I get the following:

[image: plot fail]

As you can see, the first histogram is instead plotted into the last panel of the multi-panel layout. As I attempt to then plot further histograms, a new device is opened.

I assume this is something to do with my par() calls after plotting the map? Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a reproducible question, I'll show one way to do it with
generic data. You'll have to adapt it to your work.

Multi-plot can be done using `par(mfrow=c(2,3))`, and though it is simple, it is the most restrictive. Other options include `layout(...)` (which won't work for this, I think) and `par(fig=...)` (which is what I use here). A reasonable starting reference is [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html).

I'll start with your map (NB: please include required libraries with your code):

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
par(fig=c(0,1,0,1))                     # force full-device plot
plot(1, 1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", axes=F,
     xlim=c(-39,-35.5),ylim=c(-55,-54))
map("worldHires", regions="Falkland Islands:South Georgia",col="#BFBFBF",
    fill=F, add=T, bg="#7F7F7F", lwd=0.05)
```

Next I'll set up a matrix to be used for defining the plot region, mimicking the arrangement you defined using `par(mfrow=c(2,3))`:

```
xs <- seq(0, 1, len=4)
ys <- seq(0, 1, len=3)
m <- merge(cbind(head(xs, n=-1), tail(xs, n=-1)),
           cbind(head(ys, n=-1), tail(ys, n=-1)),
           by=NULL)
##        V1.x      V2.x V1.y V2.y
## 1 0.0000000 0.3333333  0.0  0.5
## 2 0.3333333 0.6666667  0.0  0.5
## 3 0.6666667 1.0000000  0.0  0.5
## 4 0.0000000 0.3333333  0.5  1.0
## 5 0.3333333 0.6666667  0.5  1.0
## 6 0.6666667 1.0000000  0.5  1.0
```

`par(fig=...)` takes the left and right (x) and bottom and top (y) percentages. The first row of `m` says that the next plot will include from 0 to 33% horizontally and 0 to 50% vertically of the screen (i.e., the bottom left corner). The first plot call does not strictly need a `par(fig=...)` call, but I like to have it there so that I reset the plot layout when I redo the plot. It should either omit `new=TRUE` or use `new=FALSE` to be explicit (arguably a good thing at times like this).

Next I'll just throw in some charts. This part is my contrived part, but it shows how it's being used. The programmatic definition of `m` and its use below is not completely necessary; you can easily define each `par(fig=...)` call manually. Regardless, the use of a simple 2x3 grid of plots is also unnecessary and this method allows for placing the histograms in meaningful locations on the map. (This can obviously be done programmatically but is completely up to you and your data.)

```
columns <- c('mpg', 'hp', 'drat', 'wt', 'qsec')
for (i in 1:5) {
     par(fig=unlist(m[i,]), new=TRUE)
     col <- names(mtcars)[i]
     hist(mtcars[[col]], col=1+i, main=col)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Be warned, though, that using `par(fig=...)` is about as manual-labor as you can get ... it can easily get dorked if mismanaged. *With great power comes great responsibility* :-)

Comment: You probably know by now that, counter to `par(mfrow=...)`, this is filling from left-to-right and (differently) *bottom-to-top*. This is easy enough to remedy, such as `rev(ys)`.

Comment: Nice work. I think you might be interested in the more straightforward solution I just found and posted as an alternative answer.

Comment: For future readers: this solution is a bit strong-handed for the OP's needs; Josh's solution is simpler and more elegant given the simplicity of the stated layout requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward solution is to manually set `par(mfg = c(1,1))`. This tells R to place the next (sub)plot into the first slot of an `mfrow`-induced layout *on the current page*.<sup>1</sup>

So, for example, you can just do something like this:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

## Set up the background map
plot.new()
par(fig = c(0,1,0,1))
plot.window(xlim=c(-39,-35.5),ylim=c(-55,-54))
map("worldHires", regions="Falkland Islands:South Georgia", col="#BFBFBF", add=TRUE)

## Set up a grid of subplots areas
par(mfrow = c(2, 3), mfg = c(1, 1))          ## **Key is to set mfg=c(1,1)**

## Fill grid with subplots
hist(mtcars[["mpg"]],  main="mpg",  col=2)
hist(mtcars[["hp"]],   main="hp",   col=3)
hist(mtcars[["cyl"]],  main="cyl",  col=4)
plot.new()                                   ## Skip plotting into this cell
hist(mtcars[["disp"]], main="dip",  col=5)
hist(mtcars[["drat"]], main="drat", col=6)
```

[image]

<sup>1</sup> You need to set `par(mfg=...)` this explicitly because, for an `m`-by-`n` layout, R's default behavior is to set `par(mfg=c(m,n))`; that sets things up so that the next plot will go into the first slot of a layout on the *next page* -- not what you want in this case.

Comment: Oh, crap, that's awesome! This is incredibly useful in day-to-day tinkering as well, not just a one-off, thereby reducing the need for my `par(fig)` manual solution. (`par(fig)` is still useful when a non-trivial layout is desired.)

Comment: @r2evans -- Haha. Glad you appreciated it as much as I did. Makes it worth having written that up! And yes, I agree: `par(fig=...)` et al. provide the most flexibility (followed first by `layout()` and then finally by `par(mfcol=...)` and `par(mfrow=...)`).